# How to send multiple queries in order to sort large data

Tags: rest, alm, hp-quality-center

How to send multiple queries in order to sort large data

for example
http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/tests?query={owner['MYNAME']} gives 1000 results

but in to sort one or two fields to filter results

1. owner['MYNAME'] and user-05['PLATFORM'] so i get 200 results
2. owner['MYNAME'] and user-05['PLATFORM'] and user-03['REGRESSION'] so i get 10 results

Thanks,
Sandeep S K.

Answer (score 0):

ALM supports multiple queries separated by semicolon.

> ?query={parameter1['value1'];parameter2['value2']}

You also can use comparison and logical operators in it.
For example:

```
http://ip:port/qcbin/rest/domains/Default/projects/Test/defects?query={severity['2-Medium' OR '5-Urgent'];creation-time[2016-08-02]}
```